# Check for IsNullOrEmpty with inline concatenation

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
var result = info.FirstName + " " + "(" + info.PhonNumber + ")";
```

Note that both FirstName and PhoneNumber are string values.

What I like to do is if info.PhonNumber is null/empty, I do not want to show the parenthesis around the PhoneNumber. I know how to use the IsNullOrEmpty method in which case I need to use the *if* statement but is there a more efficient way to do inline validation of to check to see if info.PhoneNumber is nullempty and not concatenation it if it is?

Comment: Which c# version u on.. I have seen latest ones u can use like info?.Firstname

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you mean something like

```
var result = info.FirstName + 
             (string.IsNullOrEmpty(info.PhonNumber) ?
             string.Empty : ( " (" + info.PhonNumber + ")" ));
```

Comment: @Steve Are you sure this works as getting cannot implicitly convert type string to bool.

Comment: I don't know in which planet the code doesn't compile gets upvote !

Comment: @NatePet was missing a bracket. sry

Answer (score 3):

I think an extension method is better:

```
public static string FormatIfNotNull(this string input, string formatString)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        return string.Empty;

    return string.Format(formatString, input);
}
```

This more reusable and cleaner.  Then you can call it like so:

```
var result = info.FirstName + info.PhonNumber.FormatIfNotNull(" ({0})");
```

Which results in the following input/outputs

```
info.FirstName = "Steve";
info.PhonNumber = "123.555.7890";
var result = info.FirstName + info.PhonNumber.FormatIfNotNull(" ({0})");
//result is "Steve (123.555.7890)"

info.FirstName = "Jerry";
info.PhonNumber = "";
var result = info.FirstName + info.PhonNumber.FormatIfNotNull(" ({0})");
//result is "Steve"
```

Note that I kept the typo "PhonNumber" as your post includes it.

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rb4QUO)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer $""

```
var result = $"{info.FirstName} {(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(info.PhonNumber) ? $"({info.PhonNumber})" : "")}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick shot being on the road:

```
var result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(info.PhoneNumber) ?
             info.FirstName :
             $"{info.FirstName} ({info.PhoneNumber})";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use what's called a ternary operator as follows. It is like an if...else statement where the condition is what comes before the question mark and the `else` is replaced by a column:

```
var result = info.FirstName + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(info.PhonNumber) ?  "" : " " + "(" + info.PhonNumber + ")");
```